# Switch Collection In a Foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops, generics

Both of the collections have ExternalIds. How would I change the collection the foreach uses depending if the argument type is 1 or 2. Do I have to do two separate loops or can I somehow use a collection T ?

```
        public ActionResult Details(string id, int type)
        {
           IEnumerable<Album> collection1 = ASR.Albums;
           IEnumerable<Track> collection2 = TSR.Tracks;


           foreach (var item in collection1)
           {
               var result = item.ExternalIds.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
               if (result != null)
               {
                   return View(item);
               }
           }
           return View();
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just have two methods?  1 for albums and 1 for tracks?  That will make the intent a lot clearer.

Comment: You need to use common base type for `Album` and `Track`. It could be an interface or base class. Then use that abstraction to apply your logic

Comment: @DarrenYoung Maybe he wants to follow [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle? Don't you?

Comment: @DarrenYoung Because the two methods would do the same thing. I know how to solve the problem but I want to know how to solve it the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an interface with ExternalIds as member, let Album and Track derive from that interface.

```
    public interface IExternalIds
    {
        public IEnumerable<SomeType> ExternalIds { get; }
    }

    public class Album: IExternalIds
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Track: IExternalIds
    {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult Details(string id, int type)
    {
       IEnumerable<Album> collection1 = ASR.Albums;
       IEnumerable<Track> collection2 = TSR.Tracks;
       var collectionToUse = ((type == 1) ? collection1 : collection2)
        as IEnumerable<IExternalIds>;

       foreach (var item in collectionToUse)
       {
           var result = item.ExternalIds.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
           if (result != null)
           {
               return View(item);
           }
       }
       return View();
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a C# IDE around here, but what is the error?

Comment: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Album>' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Track>'

Comment: @MichelKeijzers `collection1` and `collection2`  has to be assignment compatible to each other or sharing same base type making it possible to assign it to IEnumerable<BaseType>.

Comment: I adjusted (but it's based on a guess that might work in the right direction).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wanted them to have a base class/interface. Let me exemplify this for you:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    public List<YourListType> ExternalIds { get; set; }
}
```

Then you implement the IEntity interface in both your classes:

```
public class Album : IEntity
{
    public List<YourListType> ExternalIds { get; set; }
}
```

After this is done, you can have your code looking like this:

```
    public ActionResult Details(string id, int type)
    {
       IEnumerable<IEntity> collection1 = ASR.Albums;
       IEnumerable<IEntity> collection2 = TSR.Tracks;
       var collectionToUse = (type == 1) ? collection1 : collection2;

       foreach (var item in collectionToUse)
       {
           var result = item.ExternalIds.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
           if (result != null)
           {
               return View(item);
           }
       }
       return View();
    }
```

So, by implementing an interface that you will implement in both your classes, you can use the **common properties** that are declared into the interface.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do album and track have a common base type? If so, you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<BaseType> collection = type == 1 ? ASR.Albums : TSR.Tracks;
foreach (var item in collection)
{
   ...
}
```

If you don't have a common base type, create an interface, add the common properties you'll need in the foreach, apply it to `Album` and `Track` and then do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<IMusicInfo> collection = type == 1 ? ASR.Albums : TSR.Tracks;
foreach (var item in collection)
{
   ...
}
```

Remember to name your interface well and add only properties that make sense within that interface for good coding practices